# ImageResizeException. Unsupported file type. Laravel Error

Tags: php, laravel, video, upload

I keep getting this error in laravel when I try to submit my form with a video.

[Laravel Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l8iE.png)

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $messages = [
            'title.required' => 'Desculpe! Campo obrigatório.',
            'title.max' => 'Desculpe! Máximo de 150 caracteres.',
            'text.required' => 'Desculpe! Campo obrigatório, preencha o texto desta notícia',
            'categories.required' => 'Desculpe! Campo obrigatório.',
            'image.required' => 'Desculpe! Campo obrigatório.',
            'image.max' => 'Desculpe! o Arquivo enviado ultrapassa o limite de tamanhos sugerido, tente enviar algo um pouco menor.',
            'image.mimes' => 'Desculpe, o arquivo enviado não é válido, são permitidos arquivos nas extensões jpg, png, jpeg, gif ou vídeos em mp4!',
        ];

        Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => 'required|max:150',
            'text' => 'required',
            'categories' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpeg,png,gif,bmp,mp4|max:104800',//104800
        ], $messages)->validate();

        $news = News::create([
            'title' => $request->get('title'),
            'user_id' => Auth::id(),
            'text' => $request->get('text'),
            'status' => 0
        ]);

        foreach ($request->get('categories') as $order => $category) {
            if ($category)
                NewsCategory::create([
                    'news_id' => $news->id,
                    'category_id' => $category,
                    'order' => $order,
                ]);
        }

        if ($news->id) {
            $path = upload_image($request->file('image'), 'news/' . recursive_dir(Auth::id()), true);
            NewsImage::create([
                'image' => $path,
                'news_id' => $news->id
            ]);



            return redirect('/news/draft/' . $news->id)->with('success', 'Notícia salva como rascunho, para publicá-la clique no botão Publicar Agora');
        }
    }
```

This is my controller, if it helps.

When I upload images, everything works, I already tried to change file sizes in php.ini, but it didn't work.

Comment: well, not the whole controller, just the "store" method

Answer (score 0):

From the error image you posted, It seems You are trying to upload a `.mp4` file (**which is not a valid image format**) and trying to use it with intervention.

Moreover, Intervention currently only supports [these formats](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/formats) : JPEG    PNG     GIF     TIF     BMP     ICO     PSD     WebP